# Display multiple items from JSON Array with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to display multiple values, but unfortunately I cannot find an answer to my problem.  I am only able to display one value and I'm sure it's a simple answer, I just cannot find it.

SAMPLE JSON:

```
[
  {
    "match": {
      "attachment_count": null,
      "created_at": "2015-01-19T16:57:17-05:00",
      "group_id": null,
      "has_attachment": false,
      "id": 23575258,
      "identifier": "A",
      "location": null,
      "loser_id": null,
      "player1_id": 16543993,
      "player1_is_prereq_match_loser": false,
      "player1_prereq_match_id": null,
      "player1_votes": null,
      "player2_id": 16543997,
      "player2_is_prereq_match_loser": false,
      "player2_prereq_match_id": null,
      "player2_votes": null,
      "round": 1,
      "scheduled_time": null,
      "started_at": "2015-01-19T16:57:17-05:00",
      "state": "open",
      "tournament_id": 1086875,
      "underway_at": null,
      "updated_at": "2015-01-19T16:57:17-05:00",
      "winner_id": null,
      "prerequisite_match_ids_csv": "",
      "scores_csv": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "match": {
      "attachment_count": null,
      "created_at": "2015-01-19T16:57:17-05:00",
      "group_id": null,
      "has_attachment": false,
      "id": 23575259,
      "identifier": "B",
      "location": null,
      "loser_id": null,
      "player1_id": 16543994,
      "player1_is_prereq_match_loser": false,
      "player1_prereq_match_id": null,
      "player1_votes": null,
      "player2_id": 16543996,
      "player2_is_prereq_match_loser": false,
      "player2_prereq_match_id": null,
      "player2_votes": null,
      "round": 1,
      "scheduled_time": null,
      "started_at": "2015-01-19T16:57:17-05:00",
      "state": "open",
      "tournament_id": 1086875,
      "underway_at": null,
      "updated_at": "2015-01-19T16:57:17-05:00",
      "winner_id": null,
      "prerequisite_match_ids_csv": "",
      "scores_csv": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "match": {
      "attachment_count": null,
      "created_at": "2015-01-19T16:57:17-05:00",
      "group_id": null,
      "has_attachment": false,
      "id": 23575260,
      "identifier": "C",
      "location": null,
      "loser_id": null,
      "player1_id": null,
      "player1_is_prereq_match_loser": false,
      "player1_prereq_match_id": 23575258,
      "player1_votes": null,
      "player2_id": null,
      "player2_is_prereq_match_loser": false,
      "player2_prereq_match_id": 23575259,
      "player2_votes": null,
      "round": 2,
      "scheduled_time": null,
      "started_at": null,
      "state": "pending",
      "tournament_id": 1086875,
       "underway_at": null,
      "updated_at": "2015-01-19T16:57:17-05:00",
      "winner_id": null,
      "prerequisite_match_ids_csv": "23575258,23575259",
      "scores_csv": ""
    }
   }
]
```

I'm using the following to retrieve "state", but I also need to retrieve "player1_id", "player2_id", "scores_csv" and other items.

```
<?php
$apikey = 'MYAPIKEY';
$tournamenturl = file_get_contents('http://192.168.4.84/currenturl.php');
//print $tournamenturl;
$api_url = "http://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments/$tournamenturl/matches.json?api_key=$apikey";
//print $api_url;
$contents_api = fopen($api_url,"r");
$json = stream_get_contents($contents_api);
$jsonData = json_decode($json,TRUE);
//print_r ($jsonData);
foreach ($jsonData as $key => $jsons) { 
     foreach($jsons as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $key => $state) {
                if($key == 'state'){
                        echo "$state <br>";{ 
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
?>
```

I'm certain there has to be a better way to go about doing this, however I just can't seem to stumble upon an answer that makes sense to me to return the output:

```
"state: complete"; "player1_id: 16543994"; "player2_id: 12345678"; "scores_csv: 3,2";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of nested `foreach()`, just use `array_column()` and a single `foreach()` to get your data:

```
$jsonData = json_decode($json,true);
$finalJsonArr = array_column($jsonData,'match');

foreach($finalJsonArr as $arr){
    echo "state:".$arr['state']."\n";
    echo "player1_id:".$arr['player1_id']."\n";
    echo "player2_id:".$arr['player2_id']."\n";
    echo "scores_csv:".$arr['scores_csv']."\n";
    echo "\n\n\n";
}
```

Sample output (using your input data): https://3v4l.org/sbYST

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew there had to be an easier way!  Absolutely solved my problem!